# Is there an easy way to make EntityFramework use SQL default values?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

For example, most of my entities have DateCreated and DateModified fields. The defaults to these are set to GetUtcDate() in SQL Server.

If I try and create an entity and don't set these values, I get an exception saying it can't run the SQL insert because the date value is out of range. Makes sense because C# default dates are 1/1/0001 while SQL Server's minimum date is 1/1/1753.

So is there a way I can tell EF to either use the SQL Server default values, or to NOT try and insert columns which have not been set?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must set `StoreGeneratedPattern` for those properties to `Identity` for `DateCreated` and `Computed` for `DataModified`. It is available in designer. Once you do that you cannot modify those values in your application - only database can set those properties. I wrote about this [some article](http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2011/03/the-bug-in-storegeneratedpattern-fixed-in-vs-2010-sp1/) because this feature had bug before VS2010 SP1 but there are reports that it still doesn't work sometimes.

Comment: Thanks, I did give that a try before posting this but it wasn't working. I'm using VS 2010 Ultimate, SP1 and EF4

Comment: In such case check that correct store generated pattern is set both in CSDL and SSDL part of EDMX file (you must open it as XML) because this is valid way to do that.

Comment: @Ladislav I am giving this another try, however I am getting errors about a Non-Nullable column getting mapped to a nullable entity property. Do you know what it's talking about?

Comment: Is any of these properties nullable?

Comment: No. They are not nullable in the database or in the model

Comment: @Ladislav I got past the error... not sure what it was but I rebuilt some things and it worked afterwards. Also, thank you - you're right about setting the `StoreGeneratedPattern` and your article contains some useful information. By any chance did you create that blog you were referring to about updating items that used a `StoreGeneratedPattern` of `Computed`?

Comment: @Rachel: I'm not sure if I tested it with both `Computed` and `Identity` settings.

Comment: @Rachel: In such case Computed will not work as well because neither computed or identity properties are included in insert / update SQL command. You will have to handle default value in the application if you need that.

Comment: @Ladislav Thanks, its starting to make more sense now :)

Answer (score 5):

One solution is to override your generated entitycontext class by using **partial**. This will intercept inserts/updates on all the entity classes in your EF context:

```
public partial class MyEntities : ObjectContext
{
    public override int SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
    {
        this.DetectChanges();

        foreach (var insert in this.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(System.Data.EntityState.Added))
        {
            if (insert.Entity.HasProperty("DateCreated"))
                insert.Entity.GetType().GetProperty("DateCreated").SetValue(insert.Entity, DateTime.UtcNow, null);
            if (insert.Entity.HasProperty("LastModified"))
                insert.Entity.GetType().GetProperty("LastModified").SetValue(insert.Entity, DateTime.UtcNow, null);
        }

        foreach (var update in this.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(System.Data.EntityState.Modified))
        {
            if (update.Entity.HasProperty("LastModified"))
                update.Entity.GetType().GetProperty("LastModified").SetValue(update.Entity, DateTime.UtcNow, null);
        }

        return base.SaveChanges(options);
    }
}
```

Or do something similar, looking for inserts/updates on your datestamp fields and removing them from the ObjectStateEntries collection?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryed to set the DefaultValue of the Property in the Entity?

Comment: I'm really hoping to avoid having to go through all my entities and adjusting the default value of every property. Also, it means if I change the default in SQL server I need to change the default in EF and recompile