# Default date is being returned from SQL Server 2014 from asp.net

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6, sql-server-2014

I am using Entity Framework 6 and SQL Server 2014 to store data. I have a table with 4 column, and the `CreatedOn` column has a default with current datetime in SQL Server.

When I add record in table from SQL Server by writing query it works correctly, but when I try to add record from Entity Framework, it fills in `null` into the `CreatedOn` column.

My table schema is:

[image]

My ASP.NET code-behind looks like this:

[image]

I also try by changing column datatype to `datetime2`, but no luck.

What changes do I need to make to make it work with EF? I don't want to pass date from asp.net.

When I see output of select `getutcdate()` in SQL Server, it shows the correct value.

Comment: The problem is that your `Contact` class has a property `DateTime createdOn` and because you dont explicitly set it, it has a default value (of `DateTime.MinValue`) which EF will save.

Comment: I have changed datetime to datetime2 in sql and set it default as getutcdate(), I updated my question, please check and give any suggestion

Comment: Why it's storing null and not getutcdate() ?

Comment: Because now (based on your edit), your passing `null` so EF sets the vale as `null`. AFAIK, there is no way other than to set the the value explicitly.

Comment: But it's not a good idea to set date in business logic, because it would created a problem in future when I put my application on multiple servers, all will give their own date and time. So for this reason, I set date in sql server itself

Comment: But you can use `DateTime.UtcNow`

Comment: The [answers here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965386/is-there-an-easy-way-to-make-entityframework-use-sql-default-values) might help.

Comment: I am using DateTime.UtcNow in asp.net and passing to sql to entities. Hope it will not create trouble in future :)