# Default values doesn't set in SQL Server table when creating by Entity Framework mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, ado.net

I have lots of tables that contain default values, such as `CreatedDateTime (getutcdate())`. But right now, the value 0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 gets stored instead.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35093135/7731479 --> that is not effective, I have to do it for each table manually for every database model update (edmx). How can I update all StoreGeneratedPattern to Computed automatically? Or why it does not takes computed automatically?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43400053/7731479 --> ado.net generates all properties and I can't generate again `CreatedDateTime`.

Are there any automatic solution?

I am using Entity Framework and ado.net.

```
Person person = new Person()
{
    Id = id,
    Name = name,
};
AddToPerson(person);
SaveChanges();
```

I want to use above. I don't want use the following and assign CreatedDeteTime  again because it is assigned in MSSQL with default value getutcdate().

```
Person person = new Person()
{
    Id = id,
    Name = name,
    CreatedDeteTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
};
AddToPerson(person);
SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Have you read this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/20141145/3563910

Comment: show you code (models and context at least)

Comment: Use the modelbuilder fluent api where you define your database context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found two solutions:

1- This solution solve for all entities that has same property such as **CreatedDateTime**

```
public partial class MyEntities : ObjectContext
    {
        public override int SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
        {
            this.DetectChanges();

            foreach (var insert in this.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(System.Data.EntityState.Added))
            {
                if (insert.Entity.GetType().GetProperty("CreatedDateTime") != null && insert.Entity.GetType().GetProperty("CreatedDateTime").GetType().Name == "DateTime" && (DateTime)(insert.Entity.GetType().GetProperty("CreatedDateTime").GetValue(insert.Entity)) == DateTime.Parse("0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000"))
                    insert.Entity.GetType().GetProperty("CreatedDateTime").SetValue(insert.Entity, DateTime.UtcNow, null);                
            }
            return base.SaveChanges(options);
        }
    }
```

referance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5965743/7731479

2-

```
public partial class Person
        {
            public Person()
            {
                this.CreatedDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
            }
        }
```

referance : [DB default value ignored when creating Entity Framework model](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40310675/7731479)

Answer (score 2):

The configured **default** constraint of the SQL Server table will **only** be applied if you have a SQL `INSERT` statement that **omits** the column in question.

So if you insert

```
 INSERT INTO dbo.Person(Id, Name) VALUES (42, "John Doe")
```

--> then your `CreatedDateTime` **will** automatically be set to the `GETUTCDATE()` value.

**Unfortunately**, if you have mapped this column in your EF model class, then this is *not* what happens. If you create an instance of `Person` in your C# code, and the `CreatedDateTime` column is in fact part of the model class, then EF will use something like this to insert the new person:

```
 INSERT INTO dbo.Person(Id, Name, CreatedDateTime) VALUES (42, "John Doe", NULL)
```

and since now `NULL` **is** in fact provided for the `CreatedDateTime` column, that's the value that will be stored - or maybe it's an empty string - no matter what, the column **is specified** in the `INSERT` statement and thus the configured default constraint **is not applied**.

So if you want to let SQL Server kick in with the defaults, you need to make sure *not* to provide the column(s) in question in the `INSERT` statement at all. You can do this by:

1. having a separate model class just for inserts, which does **not** include those columns in question - e.g. have a `NewPerson` entity, that also maps to the `Person` table, but only consists of `Name` and `ID` for instance. Since those properties aren't there, EF cannot and will not generate an `INSERT` statement with them - so then the SQL Server default constraints will kick in
2. map the `INSERT` method to a SQL Server stored procedure and handle the inserting inside that procedure, by explicitly *not* specifying those columns you want to have take on default values

Comment: CreatedDateTime is not nullable, you can not assign it null. Despite of it has default value as getutcdate() it takes 0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 because its StoreGeneratedPattern is not Computed.

Answer (score 0):

May be I'm wrong, but I have a question.
If you need to save a default date in your DB Table, why you're trying to save another date from programm level? I mean, it's easy to create a procedure and on the procedure level save the date. Something like (select getdate()...).